# What are some good 10 minute dumbbell workout for the whole body?

Tags: workout-routines, strength, workout, dumbbells

Do you have any idea's what could be a good 10 minute dumbbell workout? I'm looking for compound exercises for the whole body.

Comment: You won't accomplish much in only 10 minutes, I'm afraid. 10 minutes is roughly the time you should spend warming up.

Comment: @Alec I'd respectfully disagree. While you may not be able to accomplish much in terms of hypertrophy or serious strength, you can gain quite a bit with regard to aerobic capacity with an HIIT type workout, and you'll reap many health benefits. Not to discount the importance of thoroughly warming up, though.

Comment: I agree with Alec and so does science, studies show that 10mins for a whole exercise routine is not enough. There are no shortcuts you can take and succeed.

Comment: Not to make the member who ask disappointed, maybe he has only those 10 mins to do some workout, and sionce doing a little is better than  notthing, I would suggest to do 5 min warming up your total body , then  switch into some  compound exercises ( man maker is an aexample) . A quick research on google can give   several such exercise,  do the ones you prefer. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Nizar SE is not about feelings, 10 minutes is not enough to make any amount of long term benefits. The question is also opinion-based and very broad.

Answer (score 1):

10 straight minutes of man-makers would be a killer: [Man Makers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-6EPLtSLwU)

Could not recommend this exercise more.

Comment: Why the downvote !

Comment: @Nizar someone probably tried doing 10 minutes of man makers